# Aligning columns in Python

Tags: python, format

I want to read ONLY the fourth and fifth column of this text file

**sample.txt**

```
2012-01-01  09:00   San Jose    Men's Clothing  214.05  Amex
2012-01-01  09:00   Fort Worth  Women's Clothing    153.57  Visa
2012-01-01  09:00   San Diego   Music   66.08   Cash
```

I am able to do this, but the format of the output isn't what I want.

**output**

```
Men's Clothing                           214.05
Women's Clothing                           153.57
Music                            66.08
```

**Desired output**

```
Men's Clothing                             214.05
Women's Clothing                           153.57
Music                                       66.08
```

Here is my code (I used some formatting but it's still not giving me the desired output):

```
for line in open("sample.txt"):
    strsales=line.split()[-2]
    item=line.split('\t')[3]
    itemsales=item+"{0:>33}".format(strsales)
    print(itemsales)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
itemsales=item+"{0:>33}".format(strsales)
```

is padding out the *number* to 33 positions. But the length of `item` is variable, and that is causing your alignment to go out. Look closely and you will see that the unevenness in row 1 and row 2 is 2 positions, and that is exactly the difference in length between `Men's Clothing` and `Women's Clothing`. You need to pad out *both* variables to a constant number of positions. Try this

```
itemsales = "{0:<33}{1:>18}".format(item,strsales)
```